# Nginx - Conditional proxy_pass to PHP

Tags: nginx

I have the config below that seems to work for static files only at the moment but it is too greedy for PHP files.

This is a new frontend server where we are slowly migrating PHP scripts and content over to.

The logic being: If the file exists locally (in /var/www/test.com) then serve that.  Otherwise send over to the 10.0.1.2 server to serve the content.

For static content this works fine. (.html, .jpg, .txt etc).

However for PHP this config is too greedy and will try and run any .php file even if the file is not on the local file system.

Is there a way to only get this to run if the file is found on the local file system and if not do the same action as static content and send over to the 10.0.1.2 server?

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.test.com;

    root /var/www/test.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://10.0.1.2;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the same `try_files` statement in your `location ~ \.php$` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the try_files was not allowed as a duplicate but the following works...

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.test.com;

    root /var/www/test.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://10.0.1.2;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        error_page 404 = @proxy;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: `try_files was not allowed as a duplicate` — what?